Issue with tx.origin and msg.sender in Foundry test
I want to test this contract from the Ethernaut Level-4 (i.e., Telephone).
I am facing an issue while testing the Telephone contract using Foundry. The tx.origin and msg.sender seem to be different than expected, causing the test to fail.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Telephone {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function changeOwner(address _owner) public {
        if (tx.origin != msg.sender) {
            owner = _owner;
        }
    }
}

Here is the test:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {Test} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Telephone} from "../src/Telephone.sol";

contract TelephoneTest is Test {
    Telephone telephone;

    address user = makeAddr("user");
    address newOwner = makeAddr("newOwner");

    function setUp() public {
        vm.startPrank(user);
        telephone = new Telephone();
        vm.stopPrank();
    }

    function testTelephoneDoesNotChangeOwner() public {
        vm.prank(user);
        telephone.changeOwner(newOwner);
        assertEq(telephone.owner(), user, "Owner should not have changed");
        //Test is failing?
    }
}

The test fails because tx.origin and msg.sender seem to be different. I expect tx.origin to be the same as msg.sender in the test environment, but it appears that tx.origin is set to the DefaultSender from Foundry.
Is changing the foundry.toml the way to go to test that using Telephone we can't change the owner?
Any guidance on how to resolve this issue or correctly simulate the conditions would be greatly appreciated.

In your test (i.e, testTelephoneDoesNotChangeOwner), since you've called the changeOwner() function using the pranked address (i.e., user ). Therefore, the msg.sender would be the pranked user address, whereas the tx.origin would be the address of the test contract (i.e., TelephoneTest), because that's where the  transaction for the changeOwner() originated from.
So, if you want to have the tx.origin as the user address too, while calling the changeOwner() function, then you've to use vm.broadcast(user) instead of vm.prank(user) before that.
The revised test would be:
function testTelephoneDoesNotChangeOwner() public {
    vm.broadcast(user);
    telephone.changeOwner(newOwner);
    assertEq(telephone.owner(), user, "Owner should not have changed");
}


But the goal of the test is to show that the telephone.owner() does not change! So assertEq(telephone.owner(), user, "Owner should not have changed"); should be equal!

Apologies for the misunderstanding. I've corrected my answer. Please check.

It worked! Thanks!

Great. Kindly please mark the answer as accepted, so that it could potentially help others facing a similar problem.

You can use :
vm.prank(user, user)
instead of :
vm.broadcast(user)
It will set tx.origin and msg.sender to user.
broadcast is most recommended for scripts rather than tests unlike prank which is the preferred function for local simulation.
